# Pass event handler with additional parameters to Click event

Tags: c#, events

I am having custom control (Panel) which has some button with it.

That button have `EventHandler` which looks like this:

```
private void AddImageToLayout(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));
    pb.Width = 50;
    pb.Height = 50;

    //Base part
    this.FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(pb);

    LayoutControl c = new LayoutControl(pb, ElementProperties_Sirina_nud);
    _Layout.Controls.Add(c);
    //========================
}
```

Now what I want to do is make user be able to attach own `EventHandler` to this button.

I achieved that with declaring `public EventHandler Button_AddImageToLayout` to my custom control and changed `.Click` event to `this.New_Image.Click += (Button_AddImageToLayout == null) ? AddImageToLayout : Button_AddImageToLayout;`

This works like charm but there is other problem I am having.

New event handler I need to write must have `Base part` (which is commented up there) but I want to avoid that and want user to pass only `Control` to custom control.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: I would create a click event for each image.  Then when the image is click set a global variable to the image object.  Then when AddImageToLayout is called it can get the selected image from the global variable.

Comment: Just tried it before 5 min but I got to another problem. Problem is that when button is clicked in custom control In one case I need to open another form to chose picture and then continue with code.

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net